# how to make less jagged "volume to mesh"

Tags: geometry-nodes

Basically I have a volume cube with density controlled by a texture. I then convert that volume to a mesh. This leave me with jagged stepped edges, which is not ideal, and increasing the resolution doesn't really help because it is still jagged. I would like the result to be smooth and nice.

Here is an image of the undesired behavior

[image: Bad behavior]

Obviously adding smooth shading helps, but still bad

[image: bad with smooth shading]

If I crank up the blur attribute to 30, it does smooth out the detail, but it also modifies the shape, sometimes in a bad way (and also can be slow)

[image: smooth shading and blur]

I found a post referencing a Mesh to sdf volume node, but I can't seem to find that node in blender 4.0.2.

Here is what my node setup approximately looks like
[image]

[image: node setup]

Comment: What about increasing the voxel resolution ?

Comment: can u pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild manually? thx

Comment: @Lutzi increasing voxel resolution doesn't remove the jagged edges it just makes them smaller and makes everything slower

Comment: @Chris I added the blend

Answer (score 2):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

*NB: to be continued - Documentation under work*

#### Objective

To smooth a surface generated by a *Volume to Mesh* node, removing short wavelength features but preserving long wavelength ones.

The following picture compares the achieved result from a *Wave Texture* node, to a reference surface corresponding to a thicken sphere, using the same voxel size. Left hand side pictures are rendered using *Studio* lighting set to *outdoor* with 35.5° rotation. Right hand side pictures are rendered using *MatCap* lighting set to *reflection_check_vertical*.

[image: Results - Comparison with a sphere]

#### Approach

Assimilating voxels to sensors, a [Sensor-Shift](https://digital-photography-school.com/understanding-sensor-shift-technology-high-resolution-images/) technique is implemented combining *Volume to Mesh* and *Geometry Proximity* nodes. Multiple surfaces of the same density field are generated using a *Volume Cube* node shifted by half the voxel size in different directions. These surfaces are blended to create the final result. *It is to keep in mind that features smaller than the voxel size are not captured. As a sensor, the voxel behaves like a low pass filter. So shifting its position by half its size means that it is sampling the same information.*

Using smooth shading, the following picture illustrates how each sampled direction is contributing to the final result labelled *All*, *None* corresponding to the initial sampling. Other pictures are achieved by blending this initial surface with a single new surface.
The solution labelled *Vertex* is achieved by moving new voxels to the vertices of the initial voxels. Even if it is smoother, this is not enough, particularly close to the lower left corner.
Solutions labelled *Face* are achieved by moving new voxels to the face centre of the initial voxels. Shifting in X direction contributes the most to the smoothing.
Solutions labelled *Edge* are achieved by moving new voxels to the edge centre of the initial voxels. Once again, shifting in X direction contributes the most to the smoothing.

[image: Successive shifts]

#### Geometry Nodes Graph

##### To blend samples

[image: GN Main]

**1.** The reference surface is generated without shifting.
**2.** This initial surface is projected to successive sampled surfaces. For very coarse sampling, it might help to smooth the vertices *Position* of this initial guess using a *Blur Attribute* node. But the original surface position must be preserved to blend with the others, through a *Capture Attribute* node.
**3.** The surfaces to blend count is initialized to 1.
**4.** Every combination of directions X, Y and Z is used as shifting. New positions computed by projecting the initial guess on the newly sampled surface are accumulated and the counter is incremented.
**5.** The final surface is computed by averaging all sampled directions.
**6.** Through the *Group Input* node, rendering is controlled:
**6.1.** *Smooth*: to display the initial guess or the blended surfaces.
**6.2.** *Shade Smooth*: to activate smooth shading.
**6.3.** *Blur*: to apply a post-processing smoother.

##### To sample

[image: GN Sampling]

**1.** A surface is generated by shifting the sensor.
**2.** The vertices of the initial surface (i.e. without shifting) are projected on this new surface using a *Geometry Proximity* node with *Faces* as target elements.
**3.** Projected vertices position is accumulated in the field *Position*.
**4.** The projection-accumulation is triggered by a *Capture Attribute* node.
**5.** The counter of accumulated surfaces is incremented.

##### To capture snapshot

[image: GN Sensor]

*NB: To manage the voxels position, the origin of the coordinate system is shifted instead of shifting the sensor (i.e. the Volume Cube).*
**1.** .
**2.** .
**3.** .
**4.** .
**5.** .
**6.** .
**7.** .
**8.** .
**9.** .
**1.** .

##### To compute density

[image: GN Wave density]

**1.** .
**2.** .
**3.** .
**4.** .
**5.** .
**6.** .
**7.** .
**8.** .
**9.** .
**1.** .
[image: GN Sphere density]

**1.** .
**2.** .
**3.** .
**4.** .
**5.** .
**6.** .
**7.** .
**8.** .
**9.** .
**1.** .

#### Resources

**Blender file:** [image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could remesh again using the *Remesh* modifier after the geonodes mod:

[image]

[image]